# Spark submit with master as yarn-client (windows) gives Error "Could not find or load main class"

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have installed Hadoop2.7.1 with spark 1.4.1 on windows 8.1

When I execute below command

```
cd spark
spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi  --master yarn --deploy-mode client lib/spark-examples*.jar  10
```

I get below error in JobHistoryServer log

```
Error: Could not find or load main class '-Dspark.externalBlockStore.folderName=spark-262c4697-ef0c-4042-af0c-8106b08574fb'
```

I did further debugging(along searching net) and could get hold of container cmd script where below sections(other lines are omitted) are given

```
...
@set CLASSPATH=C:/tmp/hadoop-xyz/nm-local-dir/usercache/xyz/appcache/application_1487502025818_0003/container_1487502025818_0003_02_000001/classpath-3207656532274684591.jar
...
@call %JAVA_HOME%/bin/java -server -Xmx512m -Djava.io.tmpdir=%PWD%/tmp '-Dspark.fileserver.uri=http://192.168.1.2:34814' '-Dspark.app.name=Spark shell' '-Dspark.driver.port=34810' '-Dspark.repl.class.uri=http://192.168.1.2:34785' '-Dspark.driver.host=192.168.1.2' '-Dspark.externalBlockStore.folderName=spark-dd9f3f84-6cf4-4ff8-b0f6-7ff84daf74bc' '-Dspark.master=yarn-client' '-Dspark.driver.appUIAddress=http://192.168.1.2:4040' '-Dspark.jars=' '-Dspark.executor.id=driver' -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=/dep/logs/userlogs/application_1487502025818_0003/container_1487502025818_0003_02_000001 org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher --arg '192.168.1.2:34810' --executor-memory 1024m --executor-cores 1 --num-executors  2 1> /dep/logs/userlogs/application_1487502025818_0003/container_1487502025818_0003_02_000001/stdout 2> /dep/logs/userlogs/application_1487502025818_0003/container_1487502025818_0003_02_000001/stderr
```

I check relevant files for CLASSPATH, looks OK. The main class `org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher` is available in spark assembly jar which is part of container jar

So, what could be the issue here? I searched net and found many discussions, but are for unix variants, but not many for Windows. I am wondering whether spark submit really works on Windows (yarn-client mode only, standalone cluster mode works) without any special setup!!!

BTW, if I run the above java command from `cmd.exe` command prompt, I get the same error as all command line arguments are quoted with single quote instead of double quotes(making these double quotes work!!), so is this a bug

Note spark-shell also fails (in yarn mode) and but `yarn jar ...` command works

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a defect in earlier version. With latest Hadoop 2.7.3 with spark 2.1.0, it is working correctly.!!! Could not find any reference though.